# Edgecolor of boxes when using seaborn catplot with kind="boxen"

Tags: seaborn

Catplot with kind="boxen" produces boxes with white edgecolors. For [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47vDx.png):

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, kind="boxen")
```

Is there a way change the boxes edgecolors to black?

I've already tried to change it using

```
plt.setp(g.ax.patches, linewidth=1, edgecolor="k")
```

which works when kind="box" but has no effects when kind="boxen"

Comment: Can you share some data so that we can reproduce the figure?

Comment: The code snippet provided is enough to reproduce the figure in the link. Data is loaded in "exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")".